# Cannot be resolved or it's not a field

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error at lines "****** cannot be resolved or it's not a field".
mainactivity.java

```
        Integer num1=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString()); 
        num2=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString()), 
        num3=Integer.parseInt(number3text.getText().toString());
        Integer del= num2*num2+4*num1*num3 ;
        Integer x1=-num2-del/2*num1 ;
        Integer x2=-num2+del/2*num1 ;
        TextView delta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.deltatxt);
        TextView x1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.x1txt);
        TextView x2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.x2txt);
        delta.setText("Delta:"+del.toString());
        x1.setText("X1:"+x1.toString());
        x2.setText("X2:"+x2.toString());
```

fragment.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Numarul2(b)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Numarul3(c)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calc" 
        android:OnClick="calculate"/>
```

So I have added that ids but they are not recognised in maina-ctivity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean `R` cannot be resolved? If so try clean and build project

Comment: can you show your imports and check if you any errors in resources files

Comment: @donfuxx : When I try do add R.id.num1txt for exemple it isn't found.

Comment: @Raghunandan That's all I have written. No errors. My imports are" num1,num2,num3,num1txt,num2txt,num3txt,delta,x1,x2.

Comment: @user3450385 i was taking about import statements. And i was guessign you had `import android.R;` and R.java is not generated if you have errors in resources files that is pointed in the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written bad:

```
android:OnClick="calculate" />
```

should be:

```
android:onClick="calculate" />
```

R won't compile when you misspell something.

Comment: You're welcome. But I'm no sir... ;) Don't forget to accept my answer, if you found it helpful.